# Android - String to Integer then Integer to increase the String value - Json

Tags: android, json, string, integer

String value comes like float value, then I need to convert it into integer after that I want increment integer value means string will automatically get new string from j-son. How to handle this problem ?

Comment: can you share the json and explain more what you want to achieve?

Comment: well ... did you try to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
String stringValue = "2.3"; 
int intValue = Integer.valueOf(stringValue);
intValue++;
stringValue = String.valueOf(intValue);
```

I don't my IDE with me so maybe you should have to add try/catch etc.

Answer (score 0):

From String to float use

```
float f = Float.parseFloat("1235.00"); // replace with your string
```

From String to int use

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("741125");   // replace with your string
```

From int or float to String use

```
String s = String.valueOf(yourIntOrFloat);
```

For increment use

```
i++;
```

or

```
i=i+1;
```